# SSRS multiple reports per PDF?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a task that needs to create a 6-page SSRS report in PDF format.  Each page will have a different dataset and SQL query, and I need to include them in one report in separate pages with page numbers.

I have created the 6 separate reports, but I am not sure how to create one PDF with each report on its own page.

Comment: Can you show us your code you have so far. ...just relevant parts.

Answer (score 3):

You could just create another report with all the reports compiled in it as SubReports, and enable "add a page break after" after each Subreport.

Adding the Page number is as simples as adding a text to your footer with `Globals!TotalPages`